# Breaking a system into sub systems

Tags: architecture, theory

This was a question given in class.

A hospital has launched an e channeling service to allow patients to allow patients to make online  appointments for doctors.In this  the system provides facilities to search for doctors, make an appointment for consultation time and to pay using credit card.The patients can search for doctors based on their specialty and availability.After successful completion of payment the patient receives a reference number and details for the appointmentAall appointment details are needed to be stored for internal accounting purposes and future references.

**If this system is to be divide into subsystems, what are the possible sub systems? Modularize one of the sub systems and write the modules into which that sub system modularized?**

I don't have a practical knowledge, so help me to answer this question please.
My answer is: 
Possible sub systems are

> Accountancy,   Information Processing,   Appointment.

I modularized the sub system Appointment to the following modules:

> Doctor,Patient,Appointment Detail

**How should I break a system into sub systems?What are the fact I should consider?** .Is my answer correct?

Answer (score 1):

Before asking in an open media like this, the first thing you should do is asking your teacher or colleagues first. It will be better because you can learn better when learning together, rather than recieving answer from here.

Taken that aside, I answer your question with a brief explanation of how a system can be divided into subsystems.

A system can run by itself. A system also can be joined with other systems, which they act as subsystems, creating a new bigger system (let me call it supersystem). So the most minimum requirement needed by a subsystem is `it can run by itself`.

Some subsystems may be a requirement by the supersystem, or it can be optional (features).

**Example**

One example of a system (supersystem) is a car. A car is a system created by collections of subsystems. An audio system in a car is subsystem (audio can still play even if has been separated by the car and a car can still move without audio, so audio is an `optional` subsystem). The same happens with air conditioners. You can call them features.

A wheel is also a subsystem, but is a `mandatory` (required), because a car cannot move without a wheel. Yes it can still working but since the benefit of a car is because they move, removing the move functionality from a car breaks the system. A wheel on the other hand, can still works well without a car.

For brake, it is argueable since even if a car can still move without brake, it is very dangerous to do so. In software, you can treat the brake as `enhanced functionality`, maybe something like error handling, bad request handling, use case exceptions, etc.

That is primarily my opinion